# How can I access a JSON Object in HTML with python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hello i hope someone can help me solve the issue I am encountering. I am trying to access a JSON object inside the HTML. Below i will attach the HTML (a shortened version bc the JSON output is huge) and my attempt.

HTML :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2">
    <meta data-rh="true" property="og:type" content="product"/><meta data-rh="true" property="og:title" content="Funko POP! Pokémon Aquana Vinyl - GAMESHOP Marli"/><meta data-rh="true" property="og:url" content="https://www.gameshop-marli.de/p/funko-pop-pokemon-aquana-vinyl"/><meta data-rh="true" property="og:image" content="https://www.gameshop-marli.de/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_00.png&amp;shop=85205512"/><meta data-rh="true" property="og:image:width" content="1000"/><meta data-rh="true" property="og:image:height" content="800"/><meta data-rh="true" property="og:price:amount" content="13.99"/><meta data-rh="true" property="og:price:currency" content="EUR"/><meta data-rh="true" name="description" content="Aus Funkos beliebter &#x27;POP!&#x27;-Reihe kommt diese coole Vinyl-Figur. Sie ist ca. 9 cm groß und wird in einer Fensterbox geliefert."/><meta data-rh="true" property="og:description" content="Aus Funkos beliebter &#x27;POP!&#x27;-Reihe kommt diese coole Vinyl-Figur. Sie ist ca. 9 cm groß und wird in einer Fensterbox geliefert."/>
    <title data-rh="true">Funko POP! Pokémon Aquana Vinyl - GAMESHOP Marli</title>
    <link rel="preload" href="/static/assets/oswald-v24-latin_cyrillic-regular-0aa64696cb06037f6f08.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous"/><link rel="preload" href="/static/assets/oswald-v24-latin_cyrillic-700-b9997837d0e584da3f67.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <script nonce="YzU0NzA0MmQtNjk4Yi00ODU4LTk5MjUtNmU2Y2M0MGEzNGEz">(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
              (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
              m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
              })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
              ga('create','UA-79023406-1','auto');
              ga('set','anonymizeIp',true);</script>
    <link data-chunk="app" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/app-74bf1fed557a9ddeb7b2.css"><link data-rh="true" rel="shortcut icon" href="/WebRoot/Store29/Shops/85205512/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/><link data-rh="true" rel="stylesheet" id="themeStylesheet" href="/themes/epages.limelight/stylesheets/current.css?settings=%7B%22colors%22%3A%7B%22primaryColor%22%3A%22hsl(205%2C%20100%25%2C%2024%25)%22%2C%22headerBackground%22%3A%22hsl(57%2C%20100%25%2C%2071.8%25)%22%2C%22footerColor%22%3A%22hsl(326%2C%2098%25%2C%2033.3%25)%22%7D%2C%22fonts%22%3A%7B%22headingFont%22%3A%22Oswald%2Csans-serif%22%2C%22textFont%22%3A%22Oswald%2Csans-serif%22%7D%2C%22customStyle%22%3A%7B%22customCss%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22logoAdjustments%22%3A%7B%22alignment%22%3A%22center%22%2C%22spacing%22%3A9%2C%22sizing%22%3A119%7D%2C%22themeHeader%22%3A%7B%22headerType%22%3A%22oneRow%22%7D%7D"/>
    <script src="/static/start-ee6a7a1f0403b0a8813a.js" nonce="YzU0NzA0MmQtNjk4Yi00ODU4LTk5MjUtNmU2Y2M0MGEzNGEz"></script><script data-chunk="app" src="/static/vendor-8eb303bee50da1762e97.js" type="module" nonce="YzU0NzA0MmQtNjk4Yi00ODU4LTk5MjUtNmU2Y2M0MGEzNGEz"></script>
    <script data-chunk="app" src="/static/app-45ea8c8f459e7607c8d1.js" type="module" nonce="YzU0NzA0MmQtNjk4Yi00ODU4LTk5MjUtNmU2Y2M0MGEzNGEz"></script>
    <script data-chunk="Product" src="/static/Product-d162cf57b1e0bb6daaf5.js" type="module" nonce="YzU0NzA0MmQtNjk4Yi00ODU4LTk5MjUtNmU2Y2M0MGEzNGEz"></script>
    <script src="/epages/85205512.sf?ViewAction=UnityViewRegisterSessionScript" defer nonce="YzU0NzA0MmQtNjk4Yi00ODU4LTk5MjUtNmU2Y2M0MGEzNGEz"></script><script src="/epages/85205512.sf?ViewAction=UnityViewFacebookBusinessPixelCode" defer nonce="YzU0NzA0MmQtNjk4Yi00ODU4LTk5MjUtNmU2Y2M0MGEzNGEz"></script><script src="/epages/85205512.sf?ViewAction=UnityViewAddToWishlistScript" defer nonce="YzU0NzA0MmQtNjk4Yi00ODU4LTk5MjUtNmU2Y2M0MGEzNGEz"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div id="app"><div class="ep-storefront-wrapper"><div class="react-progress-bar react-progress-bar-hide"><div class="react-progress-bar-percent" style="width:0%"></div><div class="react-progress-bar-spinner react-progress-bar-spinner-left"><div class="react-progress-bar-spinner-icon"></div></div></div><div class="body header-type-one-row"><div class="container"><section class="section section-usp"><div class="wrapper"><div><div class="header-usp mobile-view"><div><div class="swiper-container"><ul class="swiper-wrapper header-usp-list"><li class="swiper-slide header-usp-list-item"><span class="header-usp-list-item-wrapper"><span class="usp-phone-icon"></span>0451 6132952<span></span></span></li><li class="swiper-slide header-usp-list-item"><span class="header-usp-list-item-wrapper"><span class="usp-whatsapp-icon"></span>01520 6676745 <span></span></span></li><li class="swiper-slide header-usp-list-item"><span class="header-usp-list-item-wrapper"><span class="usp-map-marker-icon"></span>Moislinger Allee 14, 23558 Lübeck<span></span></span></li><li class="swiper-slide header-usp-list-item"><span class="header-usp-list-item-wrapper"><span class="usp-clock-01-icon"></span>Montag bis Donnerstag:: 10:00 – 18:00 Uhr<span></span></span></li><li class="swiper-slide header-usp-list-item"><span class="header-usp-list-item-wrapper"><span class="usp-clock-01-icon"></span>Freitag &amp; Samstag: 10:00 – 19:00 Uhr<span></span></span></li></ul></div><div class="swiper-arrows"><div class="swiper-arrow-right"></div><div class="swiper-arrow-left swiper-button-disabled"></div></div></div></div><div class="header-usp desktop-view"><ul class="header-usp-list"><li class="header-usp-list-item"><span class="header-usp-list-item-wrapper"><span class="usp-phone-icon"></span>0451 6132952</span></li><li class="header-usp-list-item"><span class="header-usp-list-item-wrapper"><span class="usp-whatsapp-icon"></span>01520 6676745 </span></li><li class="header-usp-list-item"><span class="header-usp-list-item-wrapper"><span class="usp-map-marker-icon"></span>Moislinger Allee 14, 23558 Lübeck</span></li><li class="header-usp-list-item"><span class="header-usp-list-item-wrapper"><span class="usp-clock-01-icon"></span>Montag bis Donnerstag:: 10:00 – 18:00 Uhr</span></li><li class="header-usp-list-item"><span class="header-usp-list-item-wrapper"><span class="usp-clock-01-icon"></span>Freitag &amp; Samstag: 10:00 – 19:00 Uhr</span></li></ul></div></div></div></section><div class="page-canvas"><div class="section site-header"><div class="wrapper"><header class="header"><div class="block left"><nav role="navigation"><div class="navigation-overlay"><div class="toggle-menu"><button class="burger-icon" aria-label="Hauptmenü öffnen" aria-controls="main-menu-offcanvas" aria-expanded="false"><span class="burger-icon-stripes"></span></button></div><div id="main-menu-offcanvas" style="visibility:hidden"><div class="main-menu-overlay"></div><div class="main-menu-wrapper"><div class="main-menu-header"></div><ul class="main-menu"><li class=""><a href="/">GAMESHOP MARLI</a></li><li class=""><a href="/c/bald-erhaeltlich">BALD ERHÄLTLICH</a></li><li class=""><a href="/c/neuheiten">NEUHEITEN</a></li><li class=""><a href="/c/pokemon-store">Pokémon Store</a></li><li class=""><a href="/c/pokemon-karmesin-und-pokemon-purpur">Pokémon Karmesin und Pokémon Purpur</a></li><li class=""><a href="/c/sammelkarten">SAMMELKARTEN</a></li><li class=""><a href="/c/games-and-konsolen">GAMES &amp; KONSOLEN</a></li><li class=""><a href="/c/fan-artikel">FAN - ARTIKEL</a></li><li class=""><a href="/i/unser-geschaeft">UNSER GESCHÄFT</a></li><li class=""><a href="/i/kontakt">KONTAKT</a></li><li class=""><a href="/i/yu-gi-oh-turniere">Yu-Gi-Oh! Turniere</a></li><li class=""><a href="/i/tcg-veranstaltungen">TCG  Veranstaltungen</a></li><li class=""><a href="/i/gameshop-marli-club">GAMESHOP MARLI Club</a></li></ul></div></div></div></nav></div><div class="header-logo header-logo-adjustments"><a title="GAMESHOP Marli" class="header-logo-link" href="/"><img src="/storage/images/20th_logo_GAMESHOP_BIG.png?hash=7aac6dd1191e7ddd81e9fc5a89350139ed67357f&amp;shop=85205512" srcSet="/storage/images/20th_logo_GAMESHOP_BIG.png?hash=7aac6dd1191e7ddd81e9fc5a89350139ed67357f&amp;height=200&amp;width=2560&amp;shop=85205512 1x, /storage/images/20th_logo_GAMESHOP_BIG.png?hash=7aac6dd1191e7ddd81e9fc5a89350139ed67357f&amp;height=400&amp;width=2560&amp;shop=85205512 2x" alt="GAMESHOP Marli"/></a></div><div class="block right"><div class="header-search"><form tabindex="-1" autoComplete="off" action="/search" class="search-form"><button type="submit" class="search-form-icon search-form-submit"><span>Suche</span></button><input type="text" name="q" maxLength="200" value="" class="search-form-field" placeholder="Suche..."/></form></div><div class="header-account"><a href="/epages/85205512.sf/?ViewAction=UnityViewMyAccount&amp;Locale=de_DE" class="header-account-login" aria-label="Optionen für Ihr Kundenkonto"><span class="header-account-icon"></span></a></div><div class="header-minicart"><a class="header-minicart-checkout" href="/cart"><span class="visually-hidden">Warenkorb anzeigen. Sie haben einen Artikel im Warenkorb.<!-- --> </span><span class="header-minicart-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="header-minicart-badge" aria-hidden="true">1</span></a></div></div></header></div></div><main class="main"><span itemscope="" itemType="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList"><span itemProp="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemType="http://schema.org/ListItem"><link href="/" itemProp="item"/><meta itemProp="name" content="GAMESHOP MARLI"/><meta itemProp="position" content="1"/></span><span itemProp="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemType="http://schema.org/ListItem"><link href="/p/funko-pop-pokemon-aquana-vinyl" itemProp="item"/><meta itemProp="name" content="Funko POP! Pokémon Aquana Vinyl"/><meta itemProp="position" content="2"/></span></span><div class="product" itemscope="" itemType="http://schema.org/Product"><meta itemProp="sku" content="7.74.581"/><meta itemProp="gtin13" content="0889698636971"/><section class="section"><div class="wrapper"><ul itemscope="" itemType="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" class="breadcrumb"><li itemProp="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemType="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemProp="item" href="/"><span itemProp="name">GAMESHOP MARLI</span></a><meta itemProp="position" content="1"/></li><li itemProp="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemType="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemProp="item" href="/p/funko-pop-pokemon-aquana-vinyl"><span itemProp="name">Funko POP! Pokémon Aquana Vinyl</span></a><meta itemProp="position" content="2"/></li></ul></div></section><section class="section"><div class="wrapper"><div class="content"><div class="product-image-gallery-wrapper"><div class="product-image-gallery"><div class="product-image-gallery-zoom-container"><div id="product-image-gallery-zoom"></div></div><div><div class="swiper-image-aspect-ratio"><div class="swiper-container swiper-main-image"><div class="swiper-wrapper"><div class="swiper-slide"><div class="ep-zoomable-image" style="--small-image-height:100%;pointer-events:none"><div class="image-magnify"><img class="image-magnify-small" style="max-width:1000px" src="/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_00.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=600&amp;height=2560" srcSet="/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_00.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=180&amp;height=2560 180w,/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_00.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=360&amp;height=2560 360w,/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_00.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=540&amp;height=2560 540w,/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_00.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=720&amp;height=2560 720w,/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_00.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=900&amp;height=2560 900w,/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_00.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=1000&amp;height=2560 1000w" sizes="0px" alt="Funko POP! Pokémon Aquana Vinyl"/></div></div><noscript><img src="/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_00.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=600&amp;height=2560" style="max-width:1000px" itemProp="image"/></noscript></div><div class="swiper-slide"><div class="ep-zoomable-image" style="--small-image-height:100%;pointer-events:none"><div class="image-magnify"><img class="image-magnify-small" style="max-width:800px" src="/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_01.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=600&amp;height=2560" srcSet="/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_01.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=180&amp;height=2560 180w,/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_01.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=360&amp;height=2560 360w,/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_01.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=540&amp;height=2560 540w,/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_01.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=720&amp;height=2560 720w,/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_01.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=800&amp;height=2560 800w" sizes="0px" alt="Funko POP! Pokémon Aquana Vinyl"/></div></div><noscript><img src="/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_01.png&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=600&amp;height=2560" style="max-width:800px" itemProp="image"/></noscript></div></div></div></div><div class="product-image-gallery-bullets"><div class="product-image-gallery-bullet active"></div><div class="product-image-gallery-bullet"></div></div><div class="swiper-arrows"><div class="swiper-arrow-right"></div><div class="swiper-arrow-left swiper-button-disabled"></div></div><div class="product-image-gallery-thumbnails"><div class="product-image-gallery-thumbnail-outer active"><div class="product-image-gallery-thumbnail-inner" style="background-image:url(&quot;/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_00.png&amp;shop=85205512&quot;)"></div></div><div class="product-image-gallery-thumbnail-outer"><div class="product-image-gallery-thumbnail-inner" style="background-image:url(&quot;/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameshop-marli.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore29%2FShops%2F85205512%2F62B3%2F022D%2F345F%2FB14C%2F5B65%2F0A0C%2F6D10%2FAD8B%2FPOP_-_Pokemon_-_Vaporeon_01.png&amp;shop=85205512&quot;)"></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="product-info"><h1 class="product-info-title" itemProp="name">Funko POP! Pokémon Aquana Vinyl</h1><div class="product-info-box"><div itemscope="" itemProp="offers" itemType="http://schema.org/Offer"><meta itemProp="url" content="/p/funko-pop-pokemon-aquana-vinyl"/><meta itemProp="price" content="13.99"/><meta itemProp="priceCurrency" content="EUR"/><link itemProp="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"/><link itemProp="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/NewCondition"/></div><h3 class="product-info-box-price-single">13,99 €</h3><div class="product-info-box-wrapper"><div class="product-info-box-vat-note">inkl. MwSt.,<a class="product-info-box-shipping-link" href="/l/shipping"> <!-- -->zzgl. Versand</a></div></div><div id="ep-app-area-product-view-price"></div></div><div class="product-info-buybox"><div class="product-availability show-stock-level"><span class="product-availability-icon in-stock-icon"></span><span class="product-availability-info">Auf Lager</span></div><span class="product-delivery">Lieferzeit: 1 bis 4 Tag(e)</span><label for="quantity" class="product-quantity-field-label"><span>Menge:</span><div class="product-quantity-field"><button></button><input type="tel" id="quantity" min="1" value="1" autoComplete="off"/><button></button></div></label><div class="product-button-container"><button class="product-add-cart-button" type="button">In den Warenkorb</button><button class="product-add-wishlist-link" type="button">Zur Wunschliste hinzufügen</button></div></div><div class="product-addition"><h2 class="product-addition-headline">Beschreibung</h2><div class="product-addition-content" itemProp="description"><h2><strong>Funko POP!</strong><span> 627</span> <strong>Pokémon Aquana</strong></h2><p><br /></p><p> <span>POP! Vinyl von Funko. Die Figur ist 9 cm groß und wird in einer Schaufensterbox geliefert. Schauen Sie sich auch die anderen Funko-Figuren an, die dieser Sammlung gewidmet sind. Sammle sie alle!</span> </p><p><br /></p><p>Altersempfehlung ab 6 Jahre </p><p><br /></p></div></div></div></div></div></section></div></main><footer class="section site-footer"><div class="wrapper"><div class="footer"><ul class="pages"><li class="pages-item"><a class="pages-item-link" href="/l/contact">Impressum</a></li><li class="pages-item"><a class="pages-item-link" href="/l/privacy">Datenschutzerklärung</a></li><li class="pages-item"><a class="pages-item-link" href="/l/shipping">Zahlung &amp; Versand</a></li><li class="pages-item"><a class="pages-item-link" href="/l/tac">Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen</a></li><li class="pages-item"><a class="pages-item-link" href="/l/withdrawal">Widerrufsrecht</a></li></ul><div class="block"><ul class="social-media"><li class="social-media-icon"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/gameshop_marli/?hl=de" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Instagram"><span class="social-media-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li><li class="social-media-icon"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MendelGamesTeam/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Facebook"><span class="social-media-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li><li class="social-media-icon"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=gameshop+marli" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Youtube"><span class="social-media-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li></ul></div><div class="block"></div><div class="providers"><ul class="payments"><li class="payments-item"><div class="payments-item-box"><img class="lazyload payments-item-box-logo" data-src="/themes/epages.base/assets/payments/pay-in-advance-f6fe942eae9f60bddf7d.svg" alt="Vorkasse" decoding="async" title="Vorkasse"/><noscript><img class="payments-item-box-logo" src="/themes/epages.base/assets/payments/pay-in-advance-f6fe942eae9f60bddf7d.svg" alt="Vorkasse" title="Vorkasse"/></noscript></div></li><li class="payments-item"><div class="payments-item-box"><img class="lazyload payments-item-box-logo" data-src="/themes/epages.base/assets/payments/paypal-5a7772a557b8329bccd3.svg" alt="PayPal" decoding="async" title="PayPal"/><noscript><img class="payments-item-box-logo" src="/themes/epages.base/assets/payments/paypal-5a7772a557b8329bccd3.svg" alt="PayPal" title="PayPal"/></noscript></div></li><li class="payments-item"><div class="payments-item-box"><img class="lazyload payments-item-box-logo" data-src="/storage/images/de-pp_plus-logo-quer_mit_PUI_540x60px.png?hash=b6adee9ffaca45fd6092fae2d7129314710f39e7&amp;shop=85205512" data-srcset="/storage/images/de-pp_plus-logo-quer_mit_PUI_540x60px.png?hash=b6adee9ffaca45fd6092fae2d7129314710f39e7&amp;shop=85205512&amp;height=22 1x, /storage/images/de-pp_plus-logo-quer_mit_PUI_540x60px.png?hash=b6adee9ffaca45fd6092fae2d7129314710f39e7&amp;shop=85205512&amp;height=44 2x" alt="PayPal Plus" decoding="async" title="PayPal Plus"/><noscript><img class="payments-item-box-logo" src="/storage/images/de-pp_plus-logo-quer_mit_PUI_540x60px.png?hash=b6adee9ffaca45fd6092fae2d7129314710f39e7&amp;shop=85205512&amp;width=600&amp;height=2560" alt="PayPal Plus" title="PayPal Plus"/></noscript></div></li></ul><ul class="logistics"><li class="logistics-item"><div class="logistics-item-box"><img class="lazyload logistics-item-box-logo" data-src="/themes/epages.base/assets/logistics/dhl-logo-418dd7caa4dbc9b3d077.svg" alt="DHL" decoding="async" title="DHL"/><noscript><img class="logistics-item-box-logo" src="/themes/epages.base/assets/logistics/dhl-logo-418dd7caa4dbc9b3d077.svg" alt="DHL" title="DHL"/></noscript></div></li></ul></div></div></div></footer></div></div><div class="add-to-cart-notice add-to-cart-notice-hidden"><div class="add-to-cart-notice-wrapper"><span class="add-to-cart-notice-close" title="Schließen"></span></div></div></div></div><div class="ep-alert-overlay"></div></div>
<script nonce="YzU0NzA0MmQtNjk4Yi00ODU4LTk5MjUtNmU2Y2M0MGEzNGEz">
window.__EP = {
shopSlug: '85205512',
storeInitialState: "{\"cart\":{\"pickupLineItem\":null,\"grandAmount\":\"18,99 \u20AC\",\"taxType\":\"GROSS\",\"coupon\":null,\"shippingAddress\":null,\",\"totalBasketDiscount\":null,\"checkoutState\":{\"readyToOrder\":null,\"shippingMethodValid\":null,\"pickupOptionValid\":null,\"paymentMethodValid\":null,\"billingAddressSet\":null,\"priceValidToOrder\":true,\"paymentTransactionStatus\":null},\"paymentLineItem\":{\"lineItemPrice\":{\"taxType\":\"GROSS\",\"formatted\":\"0,00 \u20AC\",\"amount\":0,\"currency\":\"EUR\"},\"paymentMethod\":{\"_id\":null,\"name\":\"PayPal\",\"description\":\"\"}},\"potentialBasketDiscounts\":null,\"minimumOrderValue\":null,\"status\":null,\"netAmount\":\"15,96 \u20AC\",\"shippingLineItem\":{\"lineItemPrice\":{\"taxType\":\"GROSS\",\"formatted\":\"5,00 \u20AC\",\"amount\":5,\"currency\":\"EUR\"},\"shippingMethod\":{\"_id\":null,\"name\":\"Versand innerhalb Deutschland\",\"description\":\"\"}},\"grandAmountNote\":\"views.storefrontView.basketPageSection.priceInclusiveVat\",\"couponCampaign\":null,\"grandTotal\":{\"taxType\":\"GROSS\",\"formatted\":\"18,99 \u20AC\",\"amount\":18.99,\"currency\":\"EUR\"},\"subAmount\":\"13,99 \u20AC\",\"billingAddress\":null,\"taxes\":[],\"subAmountValue\":13.99,\"cartValidation\":{\"possibleShippingMethods\":[\"Versand innerhalb Deutschland\",\"Click and Collect\"]},\"mustAcceptTermsAndConditions\":false,\"_links\":null,\"cartId\":\"630201B4-FB24-C1C1-0802-0A0C6D0B91A3\",\"checkoutButtons\":[],\\"totalNumberOfItems\":1,\"productLineItems\":[{\"productUrl\":\"/p/funko-pop-pokemon-aquana-vinyl\",\"lineItemPrice\":{\"taxType\":\"GROSS\",\"formatted\":\"13,99 \u20AC\",\"amount\":13.99,\"currency\":\"EUR\"},\"lineItemId\":\"630201B4-F208-1FD0-970B-0A0C6D0B9101\",\"energyLabelSourceFile\":null,\"variationString\":null,\"additionalInformation\":{\"bulkPriceInfo\":null},\"productId\":\"62B3022D-345F-B14C-5B65-0A0C6D10AD8B\",\"quantity\":1,\"essentialFeatures\":[],\"name\":\"Funko POP! Pok\u00E9mon Aquana Vinyl\",\"slug\":\"funko-pop-pokemon-aquana-vinyl\",\"listPrice\":{\"taxType\":\"GROSS\",\"formatted\":\"13,99 \u20AC\",\"amount\":13.99,\"currency\":\"EUR\"}
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

This is what i am trying to access: Specifically the lineItem ID

```
"productLineItems\":[{\"productUrl\":\"/p/funko-pop-pokemon-aquana-vinyl\",\"lineItemPrice\":{\"taxType\":\"GROSS\",\"formatted\":\"13,99 \u20AC\",\"amount\":13.99,\"currency\":\"EUR\"},\"lineItemId\":\"630201B4-F208-1FD0-970B-0A0C6D0B9101\"
```

This is my approach:

```
nonce = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser").find("script")["nonce"]
html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser").findAll("script", {"nonce":nonce})[6]
info = html.select_one("script", string = re.compile("productLineItems"))
json_obj = json.loads(html.text.split("window.__EP =")[1].split(";")[0])
print(json_obj)
```

When I print html i get the correct section of the html unfortuantley I cant filter the JSON out :( and I have absolutley no idea what i did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There could be more than 1 `lineItemId`, so you could use `re.findall()` to get a list of them. If `html` is the correct section, you could do this:

```
import re
result = re.findall('"lineItemId":"([0-9A-Z\-]+)"', html)
```

where `result` is a list:

```
['630201B4-F208-1FD0-970B-0A0C6D0B9101']
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your supposed JSON string is not even valid JSON. But that is beside the point.

If all you are interested in, is the value of the `lineItemId` key in that JSON string, you don't need `BeautifulSoup` for parsing the entire HTML document and you don't need the JSON parser. A plain old RegEx should be enough:

```py
import re

...

match = re.search(r'"lineItemId":\s*"([\w\-]+)"', response.text)
line_item_id = match.group(1)
print(line_item_id)
```

Output: `630201B4-F208-1FD0-970B-0A0C6D0B9101`

This of course assumes that `lineItemId` occurs only once with that specific pattern in your HTML document.